# Is the ideal $(X^2-3)$ proper in $\mathbb{F}[[X]]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $R=\mathbb{F}[[X]]$ be the ring of formal power series over $\mathbb{F}$. Is the ideal $(X^2-3)$ proper in $R$? Does the answer depend upon $\mathbb{F}$?

Clearly $X^2-3=(X+\sqrt3)(X-\sqrt3)$ and hence $X^2-3$ is not zero.

I have no idea whether the ideal is proper or not.

So far, I didn't learn any theorem to prove an ideal is proper. Perhaps I should start with definition of proper ideal? Find one element in $R$ but not in the ideal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element $\sum _{i \geq 0}  a_i X^i \in R$ is invertible in $R$ if and only if $a_0\neq 0$.
The key to the proof of that relatively easy result is the identity $(1-X)^{-1}=\sum_{i \geq 0}  1. X^i \in R $
In your question $a_0=-3$ so that the element $X^2-3$ is invertible in $R=F[[X]]$ (which is equivalent to the ideal $(X^2-3)\subset R$ being proper) if and only if the characteristic of the field $F$ is not $3$:   $$  (X^2-3)\subset R \;\text {proper} \iff \operatorname{char} F\neq 3.$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$\frac1{x^2-3}=-\frac13\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{x^2}3}=-\frac13\sum_{x\ge 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{3^n}\in R\text{ provided that}\dots ?$$

Comment: ... iff $3\in F$ is invertible...

Comment: @Georges: Indeed, but I chose to leave that point to the OP unless asked for further help. It is, after all, implicit in my writing $\frac13$. Between your answer and comment, though, I might as well be a little more explicit.

Answer (score -1):

Since $\mathbb{F}$ is a field then R as you have defined it is an integral domain.  Therefore if you can prove that the ideal does not contain 1 then the ideal is proper.

Comment: The statement is true, but it doesn’t help with this problem.

Comment: The original poster said they haven't learned theorems to prove that an ideal is proper.  When the ring has a unit element proving it is in the ideal proves if the ideal is proper or not.  The fact that R is an integral domain guarantees that it has a unit in the ring.  It is in fact why your hint works.

Comment: However, one need not know that $R$ is an integral domain, and proving that an ideal **is** proper turns out not to be the issue.

Comment: True, you do only need to know that the ring has a unit to use that theorem.  If you would prefer the same thing could be said using the statement the ideal is not proper if it contains 1.  If I remember the theorem correctly it says that "in a ring with identity an ideal I = R if and only if 1 $\in$ I.  I was only trying to provide a general criteria that applied in the instance the poster was adking about.